Sensorless BLDC motor control IC
I have a 240W (24V 10A) BLDC motor with sinusoidal back-emf (PMSM) at home and I wanted to give it a try and build a motor driver with FOC.
What is the best way to learn sensorless FOC-control? Use an all-integrated driver as Texas propose or use a classical MCU and implement FOC algorithms?
Do you have any IC recommandations?
Thanks.
